# What is this IP address format?

Tags: ip

Has anyone ever seen an IP address like this?
"2601:304:cd90:78f0:ccec:2be6:b328:7f5d"

I asked a coworker to give me his IP so I can add it to the firewall rules, but I've never seen anything like this. This was reported by whatismyip.com

Is there another way to get his IP address from his home?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's an [IPv6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6) address.  You can have him Google "[what is my ip](https://www.google.com/search?q=what%20is%20my%20ip&oq=what%20is%20my%20ip)" (no quotes) and tell you what it reports and see if it gives a normal IPv4 address like you're expecting.  Another site he can visit to get it is http://whatismyip.akamai.com

Comment: Thanks I'll start using whatismyip.akamai.com instead of whatismyip.com from now on